# Unable to send push notification to ios using php

Tags: php, ios, yii, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send a push notification to IOS using php and Yii framework. I created a function as follows to get data and send notification. $data is an array which contains a message and an array inside to keep registration IDs (device tokens). I ran it on my localhost but notification is not sent to my device. By the way, the output of my function is an integer value and I cannot recognize if the message has been sent or what!?

Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
private function _pushIOS($data)
{
    // Create a connection
    $apnsHost = $this->_notificationUrl;
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $apnsCert = Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/').'/my_certificate_dev.pem';

    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);


    if (!$apns)
        exit("Failed to connect: $error $errorString" . PHP_EOL);


    foreach($data['registration_ids'] as $deviceToken) {
        $body = array();
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $data['data']['message'],
            'badge' => 1,
            'sound' => 'default'
        );

        // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification
        $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage, strlen($apnsMessage));
    }

    // Close the socket and connection to the server
    @socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);
    return json_decode($result);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21162772/3145341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer. The problem was with the pem file path. Absolute path must be passed to the function to work. The following line should be replaced:

```
$apnsCert = Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/').'/my_certificate_dev.pem';
```

Correct path:

```
$apnsCert = dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile).'/my_certificate_dev.pem';
```